# Red 5, First setup "ssl_error_rx_record_too_long" error message

Tags: firefox, ssl, red5

I am using Windows 7 and I installed Red 5 0.9.1 just recently. After it installed I put 127.0.0.1 as the IP adress and 5080 as http port. After I start the service in windows I try to connect to the localhost in firefox (http://localhost:5080) and get this error

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:5080.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

I checked my global flash settings and allowed localhost to pass along with the Red 5 folder in C/programfiles/red5. I currently have the up to date versions of JDK and JRE also. Any tips on what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you connecting to `http` or `https`?  That error should only ever occur if you've entered `https` in your browser.

Comment: Crazy, I must have typed it as https repetitively without notice. http works fine.
Thanks